# Coin collection evaluation process

Tags: assets, coins

What are some of the ways to research a coin collection you inherited.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about personal finance

Comment: Although it is literally about "money". Maybe OP found a loophole?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag

Comment: Contact an auction house?

Comment: Auction house I like it 

Comment: Lots of links here:  [Heritage Auction House](https://coins.ha.com/ref/price-guide.zx).  In particular, there are price guides out there that can give you a rough idea, such as the [PGCS coin guide](http://www.pcgs.com/prices/).

Answer (score 4):

Coin collections [or collectables] in general are very difficult to evaluate. There is very little information that is freely available. The prices are very volatile.

Given this, it is best you surf the internet and do some preliminary fact finding. For Coin Collection, most countries have coin societies / hobby clubs. You could contact them.

Auction house will only be interested if these are rare collections. If these are routine collections, it may not be of interest.

For example one can take effort to collect coin of every denomination, year, mint. There may be quite a few collectors who would collect such themes, however the sale value of this may not be great as these are collected for fun and not purchased.

So I guess you would have to do quite a bit of leg work by surfing internet, contacting a friend who knows little bit of coin collection, contacting local hobby clubs ... and if you determine these are of huge value; then go in for valuation services that large dealers / auction house provide for a fee.

Answer (score -2):

At the pawn shop, you can find initial opinion.
After that you may want to talk to bullion dealer, auction house or professional collector (who has same collections).
Coins could have only sentimental value to the owner.
You can research it by yourself. 
All I know is gold and silver coins with history worth a lot more then simple bullions.